# Is there a function to format numbers in influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm using grafana to connect to influxdb and display indicator data. I'm using SQL `select sum (siz) from quotes'like this. Is there a function that can format it in the form of 1,111,111? No such function has been found in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that can be done by InfluxDB. Grafana has a long standing issue to provide this functionality:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4252

However, this was something that was added to Chronograf a while back:

https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/3608